# Блокировка с двойной проверкой

Tags: c++, многопоточность

В книге Энтони Уильямса "Параллельное программирование на C++ в действии" рекомендуется заменять использование упомянутого в заголовке паттерна использованием `std::call_once`. Немного погуглив, обнаружил, что в других языках, например, Java и C# подобная проблема решается объявление переменной как `volatile` для предотвращение оптимизаций компилятором. Является ли использование `volatile`решением и в C++ ? Или же здесь она работает как-то иначе?

Comment: Писал я на эту тему [статью](http://scrutator.me/post/2015/10/15/parallel_world_p5.aspx), которая является довольно сложной, но если интересно, то можете посмотреть как volatile соотносится с многопоточностью. Если совсем кратко: никак, это не про многопоточность.

Comment: @bronstein87 Поясните подробнее что такое "блокировка с двойной проверкой".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

нет, не является. Дело в том, что даже в этом случае можно сделать "обход". Детально расписано на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/150276/).

Суть в том, что мы думаем, что в коде, одна строка атомарна, а это далеко не так.

```
template<typename T>
T& single()
{
    static T* pt;
    if (pt == 0)      // первая проверка, вне мьютекса
    {
        StaticLock lock;
        if (pt == 0)  // вторая проверка, под мьютексом
            pt = new T; // вот здесь на самом деле две строки.
    }
    return *pt;
}
```

создание объекта это обычно две операции - собственно выделение память и вызов конструктора. И в этом случае может так оказаться, что память уже выделили, а по адресу ещё не создали объект. И самая первая проверка теперь отработает по другому.

Comment: Написана какая-то ерунда. У этого подхода есть недостатки, но совсем не такие, как вы описали. Сколько бы "строк" там ни было, переменная `pt` не получит ненулевого значения до тех пор, пока вся функцинальность `new` не отработает (и выделение памяти, и конструирование). Реализовыватсья "в две строчки" с ранним изменением значения `pt`, как написано на Хабре, такой `new` ни в коем случае не может. Это будет грубейшим багом компилятора. Т.е. на Хабре именно по этому поводу написано именно то, что обычно пишут на Хабре - полнейшая, непонятно откуда взятая галиматья.

Comment: Может. Более того, я подобное ловил в своем коде. И только в ассемблер номер коде было понятно.

Comment: @AnT, неправда Ваша. `pt` может быть иницилизирован указателем на память, в которой ещё ничего не сконструировано. Если Хабр для Вас помойка, то я думаю, что [Мейерса с Александреску](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf) Вы идиотами называть не станете? (смотрите параграф 4)

Comment: @ixSci: Мейерс в Александреску как раз таки *правильно* идентифицируют проблемы этого паттерна в С++. Потому я и назавал его имеющим недостатки. И проблемы это - совсем другой природы, из области out-of-order выполнения, а отнюдь не то, что написано на Хабре. И введением промежуточной временной переменной, как на Хабре, эти проблемы вообще никак не решаются. То, что написано на Хабре (включая способ починки), тупо содрано из статьи по Джаве, без малейшего понимания того, что к С++ это никакого отношения не имеет.

Comment: @AnT, я не читал статью на Хабре, лишь пишу по тому, что Вы уличили KoVadim в неправильном описании проблемы. Эту проблему точно так же описывают Майерс с Александреску, более того они тоже предлагают решение с временной переменной, которую Вы не считаете решением. Не хочу обсуждать статью Хабра — не читал, но в рамках данного ответа, я считаю, что Вы зря KoVadim уличили в «неправильности».

Comment: @AnT, просмотрел статью — да, там действительно написан бред, согласен.

Comment: @ixSci: По-моемув статье Мейерса и Александреску вариант  с введением промежуточной временной переменной, даже `volatile`, приводится как пример *ложного* решения, который ничего на самом деле не решает даже в однопроцессороной системе. И при этом никуда не девается совсем другой клубок проблем, когда заходит речь о memory coherence в многопроцессорных системах.

Comment: @AnT, на 12 странице они предлагают решение с временной переменной и барьерами. P.S. в предыдущем комментарии я согласился, что так, как это сделано на Хабре решением не является.

Comment: @KoVadim, Я правильно понял, что команда `load` (для **static volatile pt**) из строки `if (pt == 0)` под мьютексом загружала 0 в то время, когда другой поток, выполнивший new, уже вышел из мьютекса? (а можно поподробнее, что именно и в какой системе на уровне ассемблерного кода вы ловили? )

Answer (score 2):

Мейерс пишет, что *`volatile` применяется для памяти, чтения и записи которой не должны удаляться при оптимизации*, и что надо четко отличать `volatile` и `std::atomic`, который *применяется для обращения нескольких потоков к данным без использования мьютексов*.

Если это не в тему - извините :(

Answer (score 1):

Может вы уже видели эту статью, если "гуглили" :), но там указано:

> Если вы укажете перед переменной volatile, то оптимизиации не будет.

Хотя, использовать `volotile` для доступа к переменным из разных потоков -
 **не корректно** , т.к. предназначено оно для для работы с `memory mapped`

Подробнее:
[Описание volatile c++](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2006/04/volatile.html)

P.S. Если я правильно понял вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

В случае MSVC, под `volatile` потокобезопасность [подразумевается](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/12a04hfd.aspx) (за исключением архитектуры ARM). Конкретно, MSVC генерирует дополнительный исполняемый код для обеспечения особого порядка доступа к переменной из разных потоков. Такое поведение задается ключом компилятора `/volatile:ms`.

Напротив ключ `/volatile:iso` задает поведение по стандарту, то есть квалификатор `volatile` отключает оптимизации и к потокобезопасности явного отношения не имеет.

При этом по умолчанию, в MSVC подразумевается `/volatile:ms`, то есть поведение MSVC в отношении `volatile` не является стандартным по умолчанию!